# Leer fichero .txt y pasar el contenido a un JTextArea

Tags: java, archivo

La aplicación consiste en generar autómatas a través de la lectura de un fichero .txt, en el cual se encuentran los datos del autómata.Estoy tratando de leer dicho fichero para mostrarlo en un JTextArea con el siguiente código:

```
 public void rellenarTablaFichero(String ruta) {
      String contenido;
      boolean estados = false;
      String[] transi;
      ArrayList<String> transicion;
      transicion = new ArrayList<>();
       try {
          BufferedReader lectura = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(ruta));
          while ((contenido = lectura.readLine()) != null) {
            transicion.add(contenido);
           }

          lectura.close();
         //  vfichero.jTextArea1Fichero.setText(    );
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

No funciona, agradecería alguna pista u otras opciones para plantear dicho problema.

Comment: cual es el objeto textarea??

Comment: a qué te refieres con que "no funciona"? qué errores hay? hay excepciones? no compila? por favor, da un poco más de detalle

Comment: por cierto, ya intentaste poner lectura en un try con recursos?

Comment: Con respecto a que no funciona, me refiero a que el objetivo de leer del fichero .txt y pasarlo a un JTextArea no funciona.Quizás el problema reside en que no estoy almacenando correctamente la lectura y quizás está mal pasarlo a un JtextArea.